# Remove the Largest Outlier in the array-Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, outliers

I have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,100,200]
What I want is to remove the 2 largest numbers outliers in the array.
The result should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10].

I tried this but its not working. Anyone can help me please?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,100,200]

elements = numpy.array(arr)

mean = numpy.mean(elements, axis=0)
sd = numpy.std(elements, axis=0)

final_list = [x for x in arr if (x > mean - 2 * sd)]
final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 2 * sd)]
print(final_list)
```

Comment: why are you using the mean/standard deviation if you simply want to filter based on the second maximum?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all items greater or equal to the second largest, use [`partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) and boolean indexing:

```
elements = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,10,100,200])

N = 2
out = elements[elements < np.partition(elements, -N)[-N]]
```

If you only want to remove the largest two, even if there can be a tie and more than 2 items that are above the threshold rather use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)+[`argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
N = 2
out = elements[np.argsort(np.argpartition(elements, -N))<elements.shape[0]-N]
# variant
# out = elements[np.argsort(np.argpartition(-elements, N))>=N]
```

Output:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 10])
```

###### difference of behavior

```
# elements
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6, 100, 100, 200,  10])

# elements[elements < np.partition(elements, -N)[-N]]
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 10])

# elements[np.argsort(np.argpartition(elements, -N))<elements.shape[0]-N]
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6, 100,  10])
```

Comment: i have 2 integers , how can i concatenate them with space? eg: 65 3? how to do that?

Comment: @babe_engineer I don't understand your question